# PhpmyAdmin - How to create an event schedule that delete expired players

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]

I want to create an event schedule that will run every hour and will check all Games for expired Players. An expired Player is a Player whose corresponding Time stamp is older than 24 hours compared to server current time.
If the time stamp is older than 24 hours than I want to -1 from the Avtv_Plrs field and BLANK the corresponding Plr_# field and BLANK the TS_# field as well.

The result (if it’s been longer than 24 hours) would look like this.

[image]

I have never used event schedule before and any help would be appreciated. 
Also I do not want to use a Conjob as of yet thank you.

Comment: What problem are you having with the event scheduler? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: Perhaps my description is not clear. I simply do not understand how to create the code to perform the functions I desire. All the functions I desire are in my description. Perhaps I need to look elsewhere for this answer. Any suggestions?

Comment: OK so I have this so far: CREATE EVENT chk_exp_plyr
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
DO

Comment: Any help? Or should I give up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me some time but I figured it out.
Once I join the game the time stamp is current time + 86400 seconds. Giving me a timestamp of Current time + 24 hours. If timestamp is less than UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
Then data is updated.
I have to make an Event for each Player so the first would look like this:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    EVENT `Game_Update_001` 
    ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 HOUR 
    STARTS '2018-02-28 01:20:00' 
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
    DO 
    UPDATE `games` 
    SET Plr_1 = '', 
    Ts_1 = '', 
    Activ_Plrs = Activ_Plrs - 1 
    WHERE Ts_1 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
    AND Ts_1<>''
```

And the second would look like this:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    EVENT `Game_Update_002` 
    ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 HOUR 
    STARTS '2018-02-28 01:20:00' 
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
    DO 
    UPDATE `games` 
    SET Plr_2 = '', 
    Ts_2 = '', 
    Activ_Plrs = Activ_Plrs - 1 
    WHERE Ts_2 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
    AND Ts_2<>''
```

and so on. Each event must be entered through SQL one at a time for some reason.